# TinyMCE shift enter in UL

Tags: tinymce, html-lists

I have a problem with TinyMCE and Shift + Enter in a  tag.

At first I was using an very old version of TinyMCE which worked as followed:
When I pressed "Enter" in an unorderded list then a new dot (< li >) was created.
When I pressed "Shift + Enter" in an unorderded list then a new white space (like a < br />) was created.

Now the problem is that I have upgraded to a newer version of TinyMCE. 
Now the "Shift + Enter" isn't working anymore, it creates an new dot "< li >" instead of the white space(< br />).

The TinyMCE is on a regular  
Here is my TinyMCE Config:

```
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
        script_url : 'js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

        language : 'nl',        
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "safari,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,imagemanager",

        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,forecolor,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|, formatselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "copy, pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,code",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,tablecontrols,iespell",

        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        content_css : "style/tiny-mce.css",

        theme_advanced_blockformats : "p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6",
        forced_root_block : false,
        force_br_newlines : true,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        paste_create_paragraphs : false,
        paste_create_linebreaks : false,
        paste_use_dialog : false,
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        paste_convert_middot_lists : false,
        paste_unindented_list_class : "unindentedList",
        paste_convert_headers_to_strong : true, 
        convert_urls : false,
        width : "802px"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Moxiecode changed the tinymce behaviour then. The only thing you could do is to write a custom function and take care of the STRG + ENTER handling (which id o not advise).